# Turning a grid into a button

Tags: silverlight

I have a 2 column grid that I want to wrap with a `<Button>` now when I do that it totally screws the layout of the grid, how do I disable the style of the button so that the grid is clickable via the button but it looks the same.

When I start I have the following xaml

```
<Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="180*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="296*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding image}" Margin="10,10,10,10"/>

        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding hoursAgo}" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Light" FontStyle="Italic"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock FontSize="26.667" TextDecorations="Underline" Text="{Binding title}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="40" Width="295" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FF3253B8" Canvas.Top="22" Grid.Column="1" >News Title Goes here</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock FontSize="21.333" Text="{Binding description}" TextWrapping="Wrap" d:LayoutOverrides="VerticalAlignment"  Grid.Column="1" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>          
</Grid>
```

If I use expression blend to convert to a button it messes the source a bit, which is not what I want

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="SelectedEntry" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="180*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="296*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding image}" Margin="10,10,10,10"/>

                            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
                                <TextBlock FontSize="26.667" TextDecorations="Underline" Text="{Binding title}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="40" Width="295" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FF3253B8" Canvas.Top="22" Grid.Column="1" ><Run Text="News Title Goes here"/></TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock FontSize="21.333" Text="{Binding description}" TextWrapping="Wrap" d:LayoutOverrides="VerticalAlignment"  Grid.Column="1" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>          
                        <ContentPresenter/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Light"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
        <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Italic"/>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Button Content="{Binding hoursAgo}" Style="{StaticResource SelectedEntry}"/>
```

now the description is not showing in the grid.

Comment: yeah i do. do you know what the settings are. i'll have a play around.

Comment: Just added some screenshots. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Blend, right click the `Grid` that you want to turn into a `Button` and select `Make Into Control`.

[image]

Then in the popup window, select which control you want it to turn to, in your case, a `Button`. :) That's it.

[image]

Comment: It really messes my style up, because it insists on changing one of my bindings to the content for the content presenter and creates a weird syntax.

Comment: It only creates a `ContentPresenter` for you... which every `Button` has. What do you mean by that? You need to post some code otherwise I have no idea what you really want.

Comment: That's because a `Button` is a `ContentControl` which only allows you to have one content, but you want two which are title and description. A `Button` here can't do what you want. Also, ticking and unticking my answer a few times is just not cool, my answer asked what you ASKED.

Comment: Actually, try changing Content="{Binding hoursAgo}" to Content="{Binding}" and see if Title and Description are working

Comment: ahh, bingo. i'm sorry i was being twitchy with the tick.

Comment: It's okay. Btw, I don't think creating a `Button` is the best way. What's the reason that you need to turn it into a `Button` anyway? Do you just want the `Click` event?

Comment: yeah for the click event. i'm sure there's a better way too.

Comment: There is a `Tap` event for `Grid`, use that instead of `Click`.

Comment: i forgot to mention it's on windows phone. so tap's not available

Comment: Install the wp7 toolkit from here (http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/75888) It has `GestureListener` which contains a number of gestures including `Tap`.